# RSA_private_encrypt() similar in GnuTLS api

Tags: openssl, rsa, gnutls

I need to make some hash signature using the GnuTLS library, for that I know that 'gnutls_privkey_sign_data' will do the job but in the 'RSA_private_encrypt' [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rsa_private_encrypt) there is a field called 'padding' that need to replicate but cant find an equivalent.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know the padding used in `gnutls_privkey_sign_data()` is not what you want? Also, `gnutls_privkey_sign_data2()` allows for other padding schemes.

Comment: thanks for now Im going to leave this open in order to edit with the correct answer